# Where to get the end-of-episode pictures?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

In season 1 & 2 (maybe also 3), each episode ends with a preview of the next episode's title on top of a picture, with a dialogue box. The pictures are visibly done by different artists and seem to be signed.

I fancy some of these pictures but have no idea if/where they could be found without the extraneous interface stuff. Have these appeared in an artbook, some online promo gallery, or possibly their respective artists' gallery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They seem to be bundled with the limited edition Blu-Ray releases.

For example, Season 2 Volume 6 limited edition Blu-Ray comes with all these goodies, picture courtesy of [the official anime site](http://kaminomi.jp/dvd/index.html):

[image]

On the middle right, you can see two postcards. These are the endcards from episodes 11 and 12 (the episodes published on this volume) free from any text obstructions. I found screenshots of the original episode 11 and 12 endcards on [a Japanese blogpost](http://ruce.blog5.fc2.com/blog-entry-3299.html) to confirm.

The limited edition Blu-Rays have a suggested sale price of 6800 yen (about 68 USD) each, and it will probably cost more to import it to another country.

Comment: I have found that the only French release of the series also has some postcards, though not as many as there are episodes in the season. It seems US releases also include a/some postcards. Bonus point: the blog you link answers my other question about which games the end interfaces spoofed :)